# boost:math:factorial2 throws an error while computing double factorial of -1?

Tags: c++, boost

The official documentation of boost library in C++ confirms that -1!! is defined. However, when I try to compute the double factorial of -1, it throws the following error
"Error in function boost::math::tgamma result of gamma is too large to represent". I can implement a code based on iteration to compute the same (if it comes to that), but would like to use optimized libraries wherever possible. Any suggestions on rectifying this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  double t  = boost::math::double_factorial<double>(-1);
  std::cout << t <<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

This is the minimal working example.

Comment: So what is -1! ?

Comment: The double factorial of -1 or -1!! is defined as 1. I have a code that would require the computation of double factorials very frequently, and the double factorial of -1 is a case that I expect to hit very often.

Comment: Just a note I found on the documentation page: *The argument to double_factorial is type unsigned even though technically -1!! is defined.*

Comment: @chris, Exactly, The documentation specifies that it is defined, but the function unfortunately does not. I am guessing that they say it is mathematically defined, but not in the library.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas, That is what it suggests to me. No special check against `UINT_MAX` and "technically" possibly meaning "it wasn't worth the tradeoff to support it here", especially if this is supposed to be optimized for a limited range of inputs.

Comment: @chris, So it means that I am better off writing my own implementation for the double factorial. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Mathematically, -1!! is defined; you can write out the definition that is shown on the Boost documentation page, or ask Wolfram Alpha and it will tell you the value is -1. Wolfram MathWorld will tell you its value is 1, by definition. *Technically* defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `boost::math::double_factorial` is [declared](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/factorials/sf_double_factorial.html):

```
namespace boost{ namespace math{

template <class T>
T double_factorial(unsigned i);

template <class T, class Policy>
T double_factorial(unsigned i, const Policy&);

}} // namespaces
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/factorials/sf_double_factorial.html) for `boost::math::double_factorial`

> The argument to double_factorial is type unsigned even though
> technically -1!! is defined.

This means that, although *mathematically* -1!! is well defined, the function does not support negative inputs.
In fact, -1 will be [silently converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to an `unsigned`, which will result in a large number-- hence the overflow.

As a workaround, you could declare an additional `double_factorial` function inside the `namespace boost::math`

Example, where for simplicity I have allowed for just -1!!.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include  <boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace math {
    template <class T>
    T double_factorial(int i) { if (i == -1) return T{1}; else throw(std::runtime_error("Unknown double factorial")); }
} }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  double t  = boost::math::double_factorial<double>(-1);
  std::cout << t <<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29a52d635de9b0a0)

**Warning**

This solution will work, because the compiler will choose your new overload, inside the same namespace, when you call `double_factorial` with a negative argument.
It is however potentially dangerous: if a future version of `boost` allows for negative values, the code may not compile anymore, or ignore the new boost version.

A better solution is to wrap around `double_gamma` to a function you define, like as follows

```
template <class T>
T my_double_factorial(int i) {
    if (i > 0)
       return boost::math::double_factorial<T>(i);
    else if (i == -1)
       return T{1};
    else
       throw(std::runtime_error("Unknown double factorial"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is [declared as](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/factorials/sf_double_factorial.html)

```
template <class T>
T double_factorial(unsigned i);
```

and `unsigned(-1)` is a very large number.

Comment: I agree that the code says so. But their documentation claimed (or atleast it seems to claim) that -1!! is defined. Copying the comment I had made before for clarity "Exactly, The documentation specifies that it is defined, but the function unfortunately does not. I am guessing that they say it is mathematically defined, but not in the library. "